# Puma caught this error: undefined method `call' for :debug:Symbol

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, puma

My rails app is 5.1.2. Everything was working fine until today I got this error when `rails s` .

```
Use Ctrl-C to stop
2017-08-17 10:49:28 +0800: Rack app error handling request { GET / }
#<NoMethodError: undefined method `call' for :debug:Symbol
Did you mean?  caller>
/Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.2/lib/active_support/deprecation/reporting.rb:21:in `block (2 levels) in warn'
/Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.2/lib/active_support/deprecation/reporting.rb:21:in `each'
/Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.2/lib/active_support/deprecation/reporting.rb:21:in `block in warn'
/Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.2/lib/active_support/deprecation/reporting.rb:20:in `tap'
/Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.2/lib/active_support/deprecation/reporting.rb:20:in `warn'
/Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.2/lib/active_support/deprecation/instance_delegator.rb:20:in `warn'
/Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.2/lib/active_support/deprecation/instance_delegator.rb:27:in `warn'
/Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.2/lib/rails/application.rb:506:in `validate_secret_key_config!'
/Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.2/lib/rails/application.rb:247:in `env_config'
/Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:692:in `build_request'
/Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.2/lib/rails/application.rb:518:in `build_request'
/Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:521:in `call'
/Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/puma-3.9.1/lib/puma/configuration.rb:224:in `call'
/Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/puma-3.9.1/lib/puma/server.rb:602:in `handle_request'
/Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/puma-3.9.1/lib/puma/server.rb:435:in `process_client'
/Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/puma-3.9.1/lib/puma/server.rb:299:in `block in run'
/Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/puma-3.9.1/lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:120:in `block in spawn_thread'
2017-08-17 10:49:28 +0800: Rack app error handling request { GET /favicon.ico }
#<NoMethodError: undefined method `call' for :debug:Symbol
Did you mean?  caller>
```

Tried everything I could think of:

- Downgrade to rails 5.1.0
- Switched ruby versions to 2.3.3 or 2.3.4

Still no luck.

Appreciate any help. Please let me know if you need any more info.

Thank you!

Comment: is your logger level debug? See if [this thread](https://github.com/rails/sprockets-rails/issues/376) helps you.

Comment: thank you @kiddorails , but still got the same error. if it helps, this error happened right after I copied pasted another `schema.rb` from remote. thanks again.

Comment: then try `rm db/schema.rb`. If you are sure your local db's schema is correct, then `rake db:schema:dump` or `rake db:drop db:create db:migrate`

Comment: thank you again. now another error occurs ! lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the database was corrupted somehow.

Since its in development, so I just `rake db:drop db:create db:setup db:seed`.

Hope this helps someone.

Thank you.

*UPDATE*

I ran into this problem again. Note for my self.

**Double check** `.env` file.